# Accessing class properties from a different package when class is marked "open" fails when using "." and "=" notation

Tags: kotlin

New to kotlin...

In the kotlin docs for declaring and accessing properties it says that you can access a class object's properties using dot notation and "=" syntax, which calls the getters and setters:

```
To use a property, we simply refer to it by name, as if it were a field in Java:

fun copyAddress(address: Address): Address {
    val result = Address() // there's no 'new' keyword in Kotlin
    result.name = address.name // accessors are called
    result.street = address.street
    // ...
    return result
}
```

This seems to work with regular classes, but if you declare a class as open and try to access class properties from another package, this seems to go out the window and you're forced to use the getters and setters explicitly. Is this correct, and if so, why?

```
package app.foo
open class FooClass {
    var fooProp = "test";

    fun doSomething() {
        // Just to show what's going on
        val tmpFoo = FooClass()
        tmpFoo.fooProp // No error here
        tmpFoo.fooProp = "New Value" // No error here
    }
}
```

```
// Different Class, same package
package app.foo
import app.foo.FooClass
class Foo2Class {
    fun doSomething() {
        // Just to show what's going on
        val tmpFoo = FooClass()
        tmpFoo.fooProp // No error here
        tmpFoo.fooProp = "New Value" // No error here
    }
}
```

```
// Different Class, different package
package app.bar
import app.foo.FooClass
class BarClass {
    fun doSomething() {
        // Just to show what's going on
        val tmpFoo = FooClass()
        tmpFoo.fooProp // Error here
        tmpFoo.fooProp = "New Value" // Error here
        tmpFoo.getFooProp() // No error here
        tmpFoo.setFooProp("New Value") // No error here
    }
}
```

The error I'm actually seeing while trying to use "tmpFoo.fooProp" outside of the app.foo package is "'fooProp' has private access in app.foo.FooClass", which doesn't make sense if it's calling the (by default) public getter.

What I expect is to be able to use tmpFoo.fooProp to access the getter, and tmpFoo.fooProp = "value" to the set the value via the setter no matter what package I'm in.

If I remove the open keyword on FooClass, everything works as expected.

Comment: I can't recreate your problem, I'm afraid.  How are you compiling your code, and which versions?  — When I copied your code into IntelliJ (with Kotlin 1.3.21 or 1.3.30), the `// Error here` lines work fine — but it gives ‘Unresolved reference’ errors on `getFooProp()` and `setFooProp()`.  (Which is what I'd expect.  Although Kotlin properties compile down to getXxx() and setXxx() methods at the bytecode level, those aren't visible to Kotlin source.  And while `open` affects whether they can be overridden, it shouldn't affect their visibility.)

Comment: I think what I was doing was trying to access the kotlin object property from a java class...

Comment: A Kotlin property compiles to a private field (if needed), and accessor method(s) with the relevant visibility.  This is an implementation detail, not visible to Kotlin code; but from Java, you'll need to use the accessor methods.  (Conversely, if a Java object has standard accessors, it'll look like a property to Kotlin code.) — Can you edit your question, showing how to recreate the problem?  That'll help anyone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was being stupid and trying to access the kotlin property from a java class and not a kotlin class.

In the above examples, BarClass was a java class.